# Python tkinter operation for pass the value from the Textbox

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, user-interface, tkinter, docx

Actually I have done a script for .docx operation. That script would count the total .docx files in the folder and give some reports. Now I plan to use a GUI operation on that. In my script I Put that folder which is presented in the python directory so it's working but I what I want here is, User will enter the path in textbox like "C:/user/app/data/folder_name" and when pressing of the submit button It will show the report. Here I attached the code

code:

```
import os
import glob
from docx import Document

from tkinter import *
def print_input():

    mypath = text_entry.get()
    files=0
    for name in os.listdir(mypath):
        if name.endswith('.docx'):
          files=files+1
    print("Total No of Files:",files)
    table=0
    for name in os.listdir(mypath):
         for word in glob.glob('*.docx'):
          doc=Document(word)
          for t in doc.tables:
            for ro in t.rows:
              if ro.cells[0].text=="ID" :
                table=table+1
    print("Total Number of Tables: ", table)

root = Tk()
Label(root, text="Enter Path").grid(row=0)

text_entry = Entry(root)
text_entry.grid(row=1, column=0)
Button(root, text='Submit', command=print_input).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
mainloop()
```

This is my new code. But I have only one file in that folder and it consist 5 tables. This code giving 2 files and 312 tables. what can i do?

Comment: Your question doesn't include a question. You've told us what you want, but haven't told us what problem you're having achieving that. What do you need help with?

Comment: Hi I just edit the code. Solve it please

Comment: Now you understand my problem? @BryanOakley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `get()` method of the `Entry` widget to get what the user has input.So something like this should work:

```
from tkinter import *
def get_path():
    #Something like this
    #replace your default path with the user's path
    mypath = text_entry.get()
    files=0
    for name in glob.glob(mypath):
    files=files+1
    print("Total No of Files:",files)

root = Tk()
Label(root, text="Enter Path").grid(row=0)
#Create text entry and add it to the window:
text_entry = Entry(root)
text_entry.grid(row=1, column=0)
#This button will call the get_path function when it is clicked
Button(root, text='Submit', command=get_path).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
mainloop()
```

Edit:You could also use the `Text` widget to display your results when the same **submit** button is called

Comment: sorry.. I got it

Comment: Isn't you want to get what is typed in by the user and then do the operations described above on that path,so use the `get()` method and pass the value to a variable,i'll edit the code

Comment: Actually it is printing what we enter in the text box. My want here is to search folder after pressing the submit button. can you do that?

Comment: simply change your  `glob` request to the `mypath` var

Comment: hey you are really cool. can you please explain by adding comments into My code

Comment: Added a few comments but I don't really get most of your code,can you comment your code as well?

Comment: Added @silverhash. I tried your above code but the output giving only one file in that folder but it has 6 files.

Comment: make sure you properly escape your  paths ,im on Ubuntu so i would do something like `/home/silverh4sh/Documents` to go to documents,i believe you are on windows so try `C:\\Documents` to go to documents instead of just `C:\Documents`

Comment: then post the output

Comment: my path is C:\Users\arunbask\Desktop\Test_Plan.  That Test_Plan consist 6 .docx files. but it is showing only 1

Comment: what happens when you change it to `C:\\Users\\arunbask\\Desktop\\Test_Plan`??

Comment: my above code works man. but when try to count the tables it is not working

Comment: @Arun Baskar,instead of putting `C:\\Users\\arunbask\\Desktop\\Test_Plan` as your path,put `C:\\Users\\arunbask\\Desktop\\Test_Plan\\*` sometimes this solves the problem